# Generating name for select element from xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I cannot figure out how to correctly use XSLT to generate HTML with a named input dropdown box (needed for reference within a form).

This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do, assuming the select element is to be named "foo" - my actual need is to set the name from an attribute in the incoming XML.

```
<xsl:template match="category">
    <form id="searchform" action="resultsPage" method="get">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <input type="submit"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:variable name="x">foo</xsl:variable>
        <select name="$x">
            <option>*</option>
            <xsl:for-each select="item">
                <option><xsl:value-of select="@code"/></option>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
    </form>  
</xsl:template>
```

I know this isn't the correct syntax - I'm pretty new to XSLT and am just trying to illustrate what I need here, which is a dynamically-named select element. Everything I've tried just sets the name to the literal string I am trying to use as a variable.
Thanks.

Comment: Use attribute value template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly brackets (`{}`) to get the XSL variable evaluated in place of attribute value :

```
<select name="{$x}">
    <option>*</option>
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <option><xsl:value-of select="@code"/></option>
    </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was one of the things I tried as I use this syntax in other places, and name="{x}" results in a "variable '$x' is not set" error

Comment: @dpbradley the error message suggest that you didn't set value of the variable `$x` in your actual XSL. Using the template in question, that error shouldn't happen since the variable value is set inline with the variable declaration `<xsl:variable name="x">foo</xsl:variable>`. Here is a working demo example : http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGcq

Comment: thanks, and between Sean's comment to the original and your followup I have it working.